# Qt and Android Gallery - MediaStore using QAndroidJniObject

Tags: java, android, qt, mediastore, qandroidjniobject

I am writing a code that needs to get an image path from Android Gallery. The code was written using `QAndroidJniObject` to write a equivalent `java` code in `Qt`

My problem is that I didn't figure out how to get the `Android MediaStore columns` to return the image path. I have tried several ways with no success:

```
QAndroidJniObject dadosAndroid = QAndroidJniObject::getStaticObjectField("android/provider/MediaStore$MediaColumns", "DATA", "Ljava/lang/String;")
QAndroidJniObject dadosAndroid = QAndroidJniObject::fromString("MediaColumns.DATA")
QAndroidJniObject dadosAndroid = QAndroidJniObject::getStaticObjectField("android/provider/MediaStore", "DATA", "Ljava/lang/String;")
QAndroidJniObject dadosAndroid = QAndroidJniObject::getStaticObjectField("android/provider/MediaStore.Images.Media", "EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI", "Landroid/net/Uri;")
QAndroidJniObject dadosAndroid = QAndroidJniObject::getStaticObjectField("android/provider/MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns", "BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME", "Landroid/net/Uri;")
```

How can I do that? My complete code is below.

```
void imagePickerAndroid::handleActivityResult(int receiverRequestCode, int resultCode, const QAndroidJniObject &data)
{
    qDebug() << "Trabalha com os dados";

    jint RESULT_OK = QAndroidJniObject::getStaticField<jint>("android/app/Activity", "RESULT_OK");
    if (receiverRequestCode == 101 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

        QAndroidJniObject uri = data.callObjectMethod("getData", "()Landroid/net/Uri;");

        QAndroidJniObject dadosAndroid = QAndroidJniObject::getStaticObjectField("android/provider/MediaStore", "DATA", "Ljava/lang/String;");

        QAndroidJniObject contentResolver = QtAndroid::androidActivity().callObjectMethod("getContentResolver", "()Landroid/content/ContentResolver;");

        QAndroidJniObject cursor = contentResolver.callObjectMethod("query", "(Landroid/net/Uri;[Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Landroid/database/Cursor;", uri.object<jobject>(), 0, 0, 0, 0);

        cursor.callMethod<jboolean>("moveToFirst", "()Z");

        jint columnIndex = cursor.callMethod<jint>("getColumnIndexOrThrow", "(Ljava/lang/String;)I", dadosAndroid.object<jstring>());
        //columnIndex returns 0

        QAndroidJniObject result = cursor.callObjectMethod("getString", "(I)Ljava/lang/String;", columnIndex);

    }
    else
    {
        qDebug() << "Caminho errado";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question.

Here is the code to the `handleActivityResult` to get the full `image path` from android `gallery` using java equivalent code written with Qt:

```
void imagePickerAndroid::handleActivityResult(int receiverRequestCode, int resultCode, const QAndroidJniObject &data)
{
    jint RESULT_OK = QAndroidJniObject::getStaticField<jint>("android/app/Activity", "RESULT_OK");
    if (receiverRequestCode == 101 && resultCode == RESULT_OK)
    {
        QAndroidJniObject uri = data.callObjectMethod("getData", "()Landroid/net/Uri;");
        QAndroidJniObject dadosAndroid = QAndroidJniObject::getStaticObjectField("android/provider/MediaStore$MediaColumns", "DATA", "Ljava/lang/String;");
        QAndroidJniEnvironment env;
        jobjectArray projecao = (jobjectArray)env->NewObjectArray(1, env->FindClass("java/lang/String"), NULL);
        jobject projacaoDadosAndroid = env->NewStringUTF(dadosAndroid.toString().toStdString().c_str());
        env->SetObjectArrayElement(projecao, 0, projacaoDadosAndroid);
        QAndroidJniObject contentResolver = QtAndroid::androidActivity().callObjectMethod("getContentResolver", "()Landroid/content/ContentResolver;");
        QAndroidJniObject cursor = contentResolver.callObjectMethod("query", "(Landroid/net/Uri;[Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Landroid/database/Cursor;", uri.object<jobject>(), projecao, NULL, NULL, NULL);
        jint columnIndex = cursor.callMethod<jint>("getColumnIndex", "(Ljava/lang/String;)I", dadosAndroid.object<jstring>());
        cursor.callMethod<jboolean>("moveToFirst", "()Z");
        QAndroidJniObject resultado = cursor.callObjectMethod("getString", "(I)Ljava/lang/String;", columnIndex);
        QString imagemCaminho = "file://" + resultado.toString();
        emit imagemCaminhoSignal(imagemCaminho);
    }
    else
    {
        qDebug() << "Caminho errado";
    }
}
```